# Changing Column name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\;Extended Properties='text;    HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';");
adoRS.Open("Select * From [Data.csv]",adoConn,1,3);
for(var i=0; i<22; i++)
{
adoRS.Fields(i).Name=i;
}
```

i wnat to change column names but when i try this it gives error "Wroung number of argumentsor invalid Property Assignment.what is problem in my code.

Comment: This isn't pure JavaScript, is it? What's the library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

the code to update column name is.

alter table tablename change oldname newname varchar (10);

Maybe you can replace the "select * ..." to the above code.